# Sort a subItems in ListView

Tags: c#, listview, sorting

Can you help me sorting a subitems in listview?

I know only on how to sort the 1st column.

Here's the code

```
 lstVItem.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [Microsoft link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319401/en-us) gives you all the infos you need.
And [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996467.aspx) can help you too.